# Hardhat and Ethers.js Mint Slow with 25 RPC Requests Per Minted Token

Tags: json-rpc, nft

We've successfully deployed an ERC-721 contract to testnet and mainnet BSC, but when calling our Mint function, followed by a `contract.tokenURI(tokenId)` call, the request times are quite long, and we are limited to about 8 or 9 NFT tokens minted before our script (and our RPC requests) freeze (Hardhat was timing out, but we increased the timeout value).

We're connecting via Hardhat and Ethers.js.

We've also tried using an API service provider and have the same problem. Stats from our API service provider tell us that for every token we mint, followed by the `contract.tokenURI(tokenId)` call - we are sending 25 API requests!

Can anyone suggest what might be going on here? Or where we could look? At first we thought we were hitting testnet and mainnet RPC limits, but our API service provider does not impose any limits.

This is our 'Mint' function...

```
async function mintToken (ownerAddress, metadataURI) {
  const contract = await getContract()
  // the smart contract adds the baseUri prefix to all URIs, so make sure it doesn't get added twice
  // this should work whether in ipfs or gateway mode
  metadataURI = stripIpfsUriPrefixOrGateway(metadataURI)

  // Call the mintToken method to issue a new token to the given address
  // This returns a transaction object, but the transaction hasn't been confirmed
  // yet, so it doesn't have our token id.
  const tx = await contract.mintToken(ownerAddress, metadataURI)

  // The OpenZeppelin base ERC721 contract emits a Transfer event when a token is issued.
  // tx.wait() will wait until a block containing our transaction has been mined and confirmed.
  // The transaction receipt contains events emitted while processing the transaction.
  const receipt = await tx.wait()
  for (const event of receipt.events) {
    if (event.event !== 'Transfer') {
      console.log('ignoring unknown event type ', event.event)
      continue
    }
    return event.args.tokenId.toString()
  }

  throw new Error('unable to get token id')
}
```